# Virtual Box Networking; How to configure bridged networking on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, bridge

I have VirtualBox on Windows 7. I have two virtual machines running RHEL, that work fine when the network is set to NAT. However I want to change the network adapters for the VM's to bridged in stead of NAT.

However when I go in to the VM configuration, and select bridged I also need to select an adapter, but there is nothing to select.

Apparently I need to install a separate driver/filter on the network adapter. However I don't know where to start. I reinstalled VirtualBox (latest version) but did not see an option to install such driver.

What should I do?

Comment: I believe this question has been asked answered before, here:http://askubuntu.com/questions/102450/how-to-set-up-virtualbox-bridged-network-on-windows-7-host

Comment: My problem is not that I cannot get a bridge working, my problem is that I cannot select bridged networking at all. The only networking option that VirtualBox accepts is Nat. All the other options are refused. Creating a host only network is refused as well.
My attempts of finding out more about this problem all point towards "my windows computer needs something extra". But what this extra is, or how I install it is however not obvious. I was hoping someone here would know the answer.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae the question you link to is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by reinstalling VBox, making sure I ran the install program as administrator.

Comment: Had the same issue. This solved it, thanks!.. at least now i can select bridge adapter